# XPages: How to hide edit box controls?

Tags: xpages

I want to use the edit box control to store something, but I didn't want to dispaly the edit box in UI. I tried to set *rendered* or *loaded* properties to false, the edit box control doesn't show, but I can't access the control since it's not rendered. Any ideas? thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the *Hidden Input Control* for this:

```
<xp:inputHidden>
```

Alternativly set the style property of your edit box to

```
display:none;
```